# sending an e-mail after 24 hours only between 6 AM to 4 PM using salesforce flow

Tags: salesforce, formula, salesforce-flow

How can i implement sending an e-mail after 24 hours only between 6 AM to 4 PM using salesforce flow.

For example , if datefield__c(datetime) on account is changed between 6 AM TO 4 PM we need to send email after 24 hours. if the field is updated at 7PM today email should be sent after 24 hours and next day after 6AM.